# What is the meaning of "momentarily" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *momentarily* in this sentence:

> Would love to chat on the phone **momentarily**.

1. For a very short time,  briefly.
2. Very soon.

Comment: Hard to say for certain, though #2 would be the more likely interpretation.  (The sentence is not very idiomatic.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Number two **(very soon)** is correct.

> I would love to chat on the phone **momentarily**.

is the same as saying:

> I would love to chat on the phone **in a moment**.

Number one **(for a very short time, briefly)** would be:

> I would love to chat on the phone **for a moment**.

Comment: My pleasure. Have a good phone conversation! :)